# Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Locale' not found

Tags: php, zend-framework, localization, zend-framework2

I'm developing a web app with Zend Framework 2.

I want to achieve urls with current locale  automatically built-in, i.e. /locale/controller/action/etc. I wrote this:

```
<?php

$locale = new Zend_Locale();

?>

<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/<?php echo $locale->getLanguage(); ?>/devices">Devices</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/devices/add"><img src="img/navbar/add.png" alt="+"> Add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/<?php echo $locale->getLanguage(); ?>/favorites">Favorites</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/favorites/add"><img src="img/navbar/add.png" alt="+"> Add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and put it in a navbar.phtml file that i include in this way

```
include("navbar.phtml");
```

in my Application/view/layout/layout.phtml.

But, i only get this

```
Fatal error: Class 'Zend_Locale' not found in blabla\module\Application\view\layout\navbar.phtml on line 3
```

What's wrong? I forget some "use"? Sorry but i'm a newbie in php.

Comment: `Zend_Locale` is a Zend1 method of localization. See: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zend-i18n

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just resolved.

The code above is relative to the older version of Zend Framework.

In Zend Framework 2 the right code is this:

```
<?php

$translator = new Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$locale = substr($translator->getLocale(), 0, 2);

?>

<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="/<?php echo $locale ?>/devices">Devices</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/<?php echo $locale ?>/devices/add"><img src="img/navbar/add.png" alt="+"> Add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/<?php echo $locale ?>/favorites">Favorites</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/<?php echo $locale ?>/favorites/add"><img src="img/navbar/add.png" alt="+"> Add</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And don't forget to enable intl PHP extension!

Answer (score 1):

**Installation** of PHP `intl` extension is must.

Comment: I can't find it! Maybe i'm using code from older version of framework?

Comment: Have you installed the intl extension ?

Comment: Yes, but the issue wasn't caused by missing intl. In Zend 2 seems that Zend_Locale  class  doesn't exists anymore.